# how does linux create it's device nodes in /dev

Tags: linux

I brought myself an Asus Transformer which is an android (Tegra2 ARM) based tablet pc. I've then chrooted ubuntu onto of Android 3.1. The chroot appears to be detecting the device I plug into the usb port but it doesn't generate the appropriate device node in /dev/.

For example I plugged in my Atmel MKII (microcontroller programmer) but it doesn't generate /dev/ttyS0. Also the same for storeage devices such as my phone.

Is it udev that's meant to controll this? It does seem to have udev installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, device nodes are normally created by *udev*. However, when you *chroot* from Android to Ubuntu, you only change the user-space programs, but **your hardware is still managed by the Android kernel**. As far as I know, Android doesn't use *udev* but a hardcoded list of hardware to watch.

Another possibility: Even if Android detects a device, the devnode would be created in the outer filesystem (Android's `/dev`). To Android, your Ubuntu chroot's `/dev` is nothing more than an empty directory. You would need to exit the chroot, then `mount --bind` the Android `/dev` to the one in your chroot.

Comment: I suspect Android uses the old method of device node creation, creating static device nodes through mknod or similar. There's a MAKEDEV script for the purpose, which creates nodes for all known devices, but it produces a cluttered /dev with device nodes for any device that can be placed in a system - not exactly useful for most people. udev was adopted partly because it was too cluttered, and partly because hot pluggable hardware demanded it - the way devices are addressed changes too much otherwise.

Comment: It turns out only selected device with google's vendor id and product number are capable of being recognised properly. You properly could get it working if you know the in and outs of the kernel. But I can't be bothered. Life too short for this.